# SPO CSOM Development without installing SharePoint 2013 on my Development Client or even On-Prem

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, rest, client-object-model, odata

We have this simple requirement.

Using Data in an  existing SharePoint Custom List on SPO 2013.  We need to develop a simple wildcard/partial string search across mutiple columns and display matching items in a grid with a new action button.  when the button is selected, the item is displayed on a new page formatted in a particular way.

Back in SP 2007, we had number of ways to do this.  But they required SP 2007 be installed on the Development client. We could also pull the data in a number of ways (SSOB, Web Service and even SQL)

We want to know if we can develop this solution using CSOM, oData and Rest without installing SP 2013 on the dev client or even on On-Prem anywhere? Only the connection to SPO. Possible? Recommended? Will I need to deploy a sandbox solution?

If this can be done, will we have intelisence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your project as a SharePoint 2013 App you will not need to have SharePoint installed on your development machine. You will get intellisense and debugging support (even when writing JavaScript).

If you're not familiar with App development I suggest you check out [Apps for Office and SharePoint on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/apps/fp160950.aspx).